# ng2-datepicker options not working

Tags: html, angular, ng2-datepicker

I am trying to integrate [ng2-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datepicker) in my project.

It worked fine until I tried to use the options. According to the documentation, I can pass options to the component using property bindings. So I tried to customize the format :

```
<ng2-datepicker [(ngModel)]="date" viewFormat="DD-MM-YYYY" name="date"></ng2-datepicker>
```

But the date is still displayed in the wrong format (and which is not the one that is supposed to be the default format according to the documentation).

I also tried to open the calendar by default with the option `opened` and it also did not work.

I looked at the referenced issues on github and none mentions this problem which is yet obvious. That makes me think that I misunderstood something.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation was not up to date. Now, we can pass options using the "options" attribute.

In **mycomponent.html** :

```
<ng2-datepicker [(ngModel)]="date" name="date" [options]="calendarOptions"></ng2-datepicker>
```

In **mycomponent.ts** :

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  calendarOptions = {
    format: "DD-MM-YYYY",
    firstWeekdaySunday: false
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

```
this.datepickerOptions = new DatePickerOptions({
          format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
 });
```

Use inside HTML

```
< ng2-datepicker name="dateExpires" [options]="datepickerOptions ">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-datepicker [options]="options"> </ng-datepicker>
```